# CefSharp with Any CPU fails to display browser

Tags: cefsharp

First up, I'm fairly new to .NET and C# and this is a project to learn C# and CEF at the same time.

I have followed a number of tutorials from the net as well as looking into the CefSharp examples to create a WinForms application.

I have installed CefSharp.WinForms 53.0.1 from NuGet, and my project is using *Any CPU* (CefSharp 51+ has *Any CPU* support).

To achieve this I largely followed the tutorial from Ourcode (http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application). I made the changes for *Any CPU* as suggested and included the basic code to load google.

Everything builds fine, but when the form displays there's no browser shown, just a blank form.

If I set the target to x64 or x86, then the browser displays as expected.

I notice in the Ourcode comments that user *Edek Halon* has had the same issue, but no solution seems to be provided. Edek, has the same setup as me, so I wonder if this is an issue in 53.0.1? Potentialy *Joey De Vries* in the comments has the same issue.

The addition of support for Any CPU in CefSharp is covered in this GitHub issue : https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714

There is a troubleshooting page for CefSharp (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting) and it seems a bit contradictory. Under *General Troubleshooting*

*1) Platform Target You must select either x86 or x64 when using the NuGet packages. If you select AnyCPU the NuGet magic won't work currently.*

Does CefSharp need to be built from source for *Any CPU* to work?

Comment: Follow the advice outlined in the Github issue. There is a known issue on certain x64 machines, see the release notes. The ourcodeworld article is missing a step.

Comment: @amaitland thanks mate! Spot on! I've found the step that was missing from the issue notes and it's working perfectly. As a beginner I was trusting the simpler tutorial, but at least now I've learned a lot about how Any CPU works.

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone is having difficulties with this, follow the Github Tutorial at the following link : https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714

Basically the code should be as follows (Winforms Example):

```
 CefSharpSettings.SubprocessExitIfParentProcessClosed = true;
 Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
 CefSettings settings = new CefSettings
        {
            CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache"), //By default CefSharp will use an in-memory cache, you need to specify a Cache Folder to persist data
            BrowserSubprocessPath = @"x86\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe"
        };
        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null); // Initialize cef with the provided settings            
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://ourcodeworld.com"); // Create a browser component            
        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser); // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```