# Error while generating a batch build for exe file generation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, desktop-application

Error Obtained while generating the exe file while batch build.

My config is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Luuw1.png)

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CefSharp.Common is unable to proceeed as your current Platform is 'AnyCPU'. To target AnyCPU please read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714. Alternatively change your Platform to x86 or x64 and the relevant files will be copied automatically. For details on changing your projects Platform see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2017    MERP
```

Also I am getting an error while installing the exe in Desktop as its having trusted Issue, I am very new to this technology. Please help

Comment: Have you considered visiting the link that's mentioned in the error? Do you have any additional questions after reading it? What are those questions?

Comment: I have checked, but i am very new so unable to understand what to do

Comment: It says you need to target a specific architecture, so x86 or x64, not AnyCPU.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, If a answer solves your problem mark it as accepted answer. If it helps you give it an upvote. If the answer is offtopic or doesn’t help at all, downvote or add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Read the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2017#to-configure-a-project-to-target-a-64-bit-platform) carefully.

**To configure a project to target a 64-bit platform**

> 1. On the menu bar, choose `Build` > `Configuration Manager`.
> 2. In the `Active solution platform list`, choose a 64-bit platform for the solution to target, and then choose the Close button.
>
> > a. If the platform that you want doesn't appear in the Active solution platform list, choose New.
> >
> > b. The `New Solution Platform` dialog box appears.In the `Type or select the new platform` list, `choose x64`.
> >
> > c. If you want to copy the settings from a current platform configuration, choose it, and then choose the `OK` button

[image]

The following links could also help you.

> 1. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41650089/16764901)
> 2. [2](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application)